# Creating expire index in MongoDB trough the C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

I'm trying to set up auto-archiving of data in Mongo and I'm hoping to do it all through the C# driver. I realize that the auto archive index is not supported trough the index API, so I'm trying to do it as a command.

```
 var command = "db.Session.createIndex( { \"RetainDataUntill\": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 } )";
 try
 {
   var res = await Database.RunCommandAsync<BsonDocument>(BsonDocument.Parse(command));
 }
 catch(Exception ex)...
```

this does not work and errors with "JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'db'."

I have not found many samples that do this, so even some better keywords to search on would be helpful.

Comment: You are passing a string with command where a json formatted text is required.

Answer (score 0):

ok, that was it; Spend too much time staring at this to spot the obvious

```
var command = @" {
    createIndexes: ""Session"",
    indexes: [
    {
        key: {
            RetainDataUntill: 1
            },
        name: ""cleanupSessions"",
        expireAfterSeconds: 0, 
    }] }";
try
{
    var res = await Database.RunCommandAsync<BsonDocument>(command);
}
catch(Exception ex)....
```